# Saving integer array using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa with hibernate and postgres. I am trying to save an integer array in a column. I am using vlad mihaceas library for persisting the array into postgresql. The entity is as follows:-

```
@Type(type = "int-array")
@Column(name = "location", columnDefinition = "integer[]")  
private Integer[] locations;
```

The corresponding location entity is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location_master")
public class Location implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "location_name")
    private String locationName;
}
```

The location ids are being saved in the db. But I am not able to display the in thymeleaf.

```
<tr>
    <td>Selected Locations</td>
    <td>[[${office.locations[0].locationName}]]</td>
</tr>
```

The following error has come up:-

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
>   Property or field 'locationName' cannot be found on object of type
>   'java.lang.Integer' - maybe not public or not valid?

Comment: Well, the message says it all. Why do you think you can get a locationName out of an Integer? That makes no sense. An Integer is an Integer. Not a Location. If you want a Collection<Location>, then use a Collection<Location>, and make it a OneToMany association between your unknown entity and the Location entity.

Comment: @JB Nizet   I want to save the selected location ids in the database as array. I already tried with List<Integer> which gave the error Use of OneToMany or ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class. As Hibernate maps only primitive types, i was using vlad mihalcea's library

Comment: That's not proper database design. Use foreign keys, join columns, join tables, and associations between entities.

Comment: @JBNizet  Database design is not in my control. I have to work with what is given to me.

Comment: Try to use `@ElementCollection` and `@CollectionTable` annotations

Comment: Then load this array of integer, and execute a query to get all the corresponding Locations. An Integer won't magically change itself to a Location.

Answer (score 0):

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'locationName' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Integer' - maybe not public or not valid?

The error has nothing to do with the use of the `int-array` of the [hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) project.

The error message is about the Spring Expression Language you used for setting the `locationName`
 which is a `String` property.

```
[[${office.locations[0].locationName}]]
```

The `locations` property is an `Integer[]`, but you treated it as a `Location` array.

What you want is a `@OneToMany` `List<Location>` instead:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="office", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();
```

And a `@ManyToOne` association in `Location`:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Office office;
```

Check out [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) for more details about the best way to use a `@OneToMany` association.

Comment: I know that it is a SpEL error and nothing to do with hibernate-types. Perhaps i could not explain my problem properly. The OneToMany List<Location mapping is also fine with me. My question is whether the location ids will be stored in the database as an integer array by this association.

Comment: Of course, they will. Check out the hibernate-types tests in the GitHub repository for a proof.

Comment: I don't need proof. Hibernate types is already working fine for me in jsonb types. I am only  confused as how to use @Type type= int-array annotation in these mappings. You also didn't mention it in your answer.

Comment: I would have mentioned it the exception message would indicate that. Check out [this test case](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/blob/master/hibernate-types-52/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/hibernate/type/array/ArrayTypeTest.java) to see how to use the int-array mapping. Just compare my test case with yours and see where they differ.

Comment: Yes, i have seen it. You have an array of integers and in my case, it is a list of objects. I am not able to figure out how to do the  int-array mapping for this list

Comment: You can't save a list of Objects 8n an integer array. Use a collection of entities or an Embeddable collection for that. You need to read the [Hibernate User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) as well if you want to succeed with JPA and Hibernate. If you skip the documentation, you will bump into many issues on the long run.